# Multiple embed deletes content

Tags: twig

In a twig project, I have several files.

- 1 template file, **base.twig**
  It contains the basic html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{locale}}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        <meta name="description" content="{% block pageDescription %}{% endblock %}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="{{path}}/images/logos/logo-onss.svg"/>
        <title>{% if pageType != "languages" %}{% block pageTitle %}{% endblock %} | Maribel Social{% else %}Maribel Social{% endif %}</title>
        {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body class="{% if pageType is defined %}{{pageType}}-page{% else %}basic-page{% endif %}">
        
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

- 1 **bootstrap.twig** file.
  It contains my css, js imports and the general code of my body

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}
{% import "macros/macros.twig" as macros %}

{% block stylesheet %}
    {% block stylesheetStart %}{% endblock %}
    <!-- build:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{path}}css/styles.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    {% block stylesheetEnd %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 overflow-x-hidden">
        {% include 'inc/header.twig' with path %}
        {% block wrapper %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% include 'inc/cookies.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
    
{% block scripts %}
    {% block scriptsStart %}{% endblock %}
    <!-- build:js -->
    <script src="{{path}}vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{path}}js/translation.js"></script>
    <script src="{{path}}js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="{{path}}js/cookies.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    {% block scriptsEnd %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

- 1 template file for a specific page type, **basic-page.twig**

```
{% extends 'bootstrap.twig' %}
{% set projectID = menuCurrent[1] %}

{% block wrapper %}
    <main id="content" class="flex-grow-1 border-bottom pb-9">
        <header class="banner text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-end" style="background-image:url('{{ path }}images/visuals/visual-{{ projectID }}.jpg')">
            <div class="container-xxl position-relative d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="px-md-5 pb-6">
                    {{ macros.basic_page_header(header_h1, header_tag, header_alert)}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="container-xxl">
            <section class="sub-banner position-relative text-bg-primary pe-3 px-md-5 me-md-5 py-6 rounded-end bg-extension-start">
                <div class="d-md-none">
                    {{ macros.basic_page_header(header_h1, header_tag, header_alert)}}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-8 lead">
                        {% block header_trainingDescription %}{% endblock %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 text-md-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light d-inline-flex justify-content-between gap-3 align-items-center" href="informatie-voor-werkgevers/{{ mainMenu['project']['children'][projectID]['url']}}.html" role="button">Alle informatie voor werkgevers <i class="if if-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            {% block main %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

    </main>
    
    {% include 'inc/footer.twig' with path %}

{% endblock %}
```

- 1 **section.twig** file which contains code intended to be used in several pages and several times in the same page with different content.

```
<section class="px-md-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2 class="mt-0 text-primary">{{info_title}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block info_content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

- 1 **accordion.twig** file which contains the code for a component

```
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{{accordionId~'-'~itemId}}" aria-expanded="{% if itemId == 1 %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}" aria-controls="collapse{{accordionId~'-'~itemId}}">
            {{accordion_title}}
        </button>
    </h3>
    <div id="collapse{{accordionId~'-'~itemId}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse {% if itemId == 1 %}show{% endif %}" data-bs-parent="#{{accordionId}}">
        <div class="accordion-body">
            {% block accordion_content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Finally my **page.twig**

```
{# CONFIGURATION #}
{% set path = '../../' %}
{% set pageType = 'details' %}
{% set menuCurrent = ['project','project-600'] %}
{% use '../_variables.twig' %}
{% extends path~'../tpls/basic-page.twig' %}
{# END CONFIGURATION #}

{# HEADER #}
{% set header_h1 = 'h1' %}
{% set header_tag = 'tag' %}
{% set header_alert = ['info','alert'] %}
{% block header_trainingDescription %}
    <p>content that is not displayed</p>
{% endblock %}
{# END HEADER #}

{% block main %}
{% embed '../../../tpls/embd/sections/section.twig' %}
    {% set info_title = "section title" %}
    {% block info_content %}
        <p>intro content</p>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
            {% embed '../../../tpls/embd/components/accordion.twig' with {'accordionId':"accordion1","itemId":1} %}
                {% set accordion_title = 'title accordion 1' %}
                {% block accordion_content %}
                    <p>content accordion 2</p>
                {% endblock %}
            {% endembed %}
            {% embed '../../../tpls/embd/components/accordion.twig' with {'accordionId':"accordion1","itemId":2} %}
                {% set accordion_title = 'title accordion 2' %}
                {% block accordion_content %}
                    <p>content accordion 2</p>
                {% endblock %}
            {% endembed %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

## **My problem**

after compilation the content of my block {% block header_trainingDescription %} is deleted.
After several tries, all content blocks defined before my nested embed calls are ignored.

If I remove the embeds from my **accordion.twig** file. it works !
If I define my block {% block header_trainingDescription %} after my nested embeds, it works !

I don't understand why this isn't working normally.
Why can't I define my block {% block header_trainingDescription %} at the top of the page?
Is this normal?
Did I make a mistake?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can't change the location of a defined block. You didn't define the header block inside the wrapper one. Also the overridden block is empty? You didn't put any content in there